# How to run all files including subdirectory with php.exe

Tags: php, windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I am try to use a bat file to run all php files on a folder and its directory.

my files and directory look like this

```
file1.php
directory/file4.php
directory/subdirectory/file6.php
```

I want run these all files with php-cgi.exe as show in below my batch code but its not working

```
set /P C= >NUL
move c:\currentfilefolder\* movetothisfolder\ >NUL
FOR %%i IN (folder1\*) DO (
php-cgi.exe -c php53.ini %%i > completefolder\%%~nxi
)
```

Can anyone help me with that.

Comment: your code is obviously not related at all with your question nor with your directory tree. Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I have a project which have php files into directory and there subdirectory, I want run full project with php-cgi.exe, I am able to run but my existing code only run main directory php files not run subdirectry php file.  I am using * in my code to select all files and directory but its not work with subdirectory, What I need to add into my code to run php-cgi.exe with all subdirectory's files

Answer (score 0):

use `forfiles` for this, and start in topmost folder

`forfiles /S /M *.php /C "cmd /c php-cgi.exe -c php53.ini @file"`

don't know about `-i` switch, but you may need to provide full path for this.

Comment: where i need to add main folder path

Comment: run it in the folder or add after ```/S``` this switch ```/P c:\my_folder_with_php_files```

Comment: Not understand sorry, If anyone here who can help on this please

Comment: Just type this ```forfiles /S /P c:\my_folder_with_php_files /M *.php /C "cmd /c php-cgi.exe -c php53.ini @file"```.